# Why Pygame wont QUIT properly?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.1

No matter what I do, the window will never quit on QUIT event. It would either ignore me pressing the X button or go into "Not responding" mode. I usually restart the shell and then force close it from the Windows.

None of these methods work and not even all of them together.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        done = True
        sys.exit(0)
        raise SystemExit
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pygame.quit()`:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Display = pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))

Running = True

while Running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            Running = False
            sys.exit()
            break

    Clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: make sure you keep the sys.exit() though because otherwise it will build up a bunch of extra processes

Comment: I believe you only need to exit if you are running in IDLE?